# Long Android build times hanging on minify

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, build.gradle, proguard, minify

Recently I've been expanding my project to include `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0` functionality. As a result I've encountered following error: *Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 112748 > 65536)*. The solution was to make my project `multiDexEnabled` as I'm using `minSdkVersion 16`.

The problem I'm facing now is the building time which seems to have no end (I've cancelled it out after 5 minutes). This happens when `minifyEnabled` is turned on. The dependencies I'm using within my project are shown below. Any ideas why `minify` takes so much time?

```
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Can you please post your gradle.properties file code. Need to check the setup stuff

Comment: @yash786 `android.enableJetifier=true` `android.useAndroidX=true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below lines in your gradle.properties and then see the results

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3096M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Really appreciate it, saved me a lot of time